# how to make increase number in 2 foreach unite?

Tags: php, foreach

```
...
$count=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT something from something where name like %$row['name']% ");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo $data[title];
        echo $count;
    }
    $count++
}
```

How do I increase a number in foreach united like this? First foreach result for a second query. Then make a count for all the results from 2ed foreach. My code caused

```
title1 1
title2 1
title3 2
title4 2
title5 2
title6 3
```

how to make

```
title1 1
title2 2
title3 3
title4 4
title5 5
title6 6
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo $data[title];
    echo $count;
    $count++;
  }
```

Basically put `$count++` inside the nested while

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reset $count for every $row, the code must be like that.

```
$count=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT something from something where name like %$row['name']% ");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo $data[title];
        echo $count++;
    }
}
```

otherwise;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $count=1;
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT something from something where name like %$row['name']% ");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo $data[title];
        echo $count++;
    }
}
```